# Add source file extension in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to tell gradle that files with the `*.dsl` extension should be compiled as groovy files, so I have added a source set with the inclusion pattern and changed the compile task includes property:

```
sourceSets {
   ...
   dsl_scripts {
      groovy {
         include '**/*.dsl'
      }
   }
}

compileDsl_scriptsGroovy.includes = ['**/*.dsl']
```

But when I run the build under a debug mode it skips all `*.dsl` files with the following message:

```
Skipping task ':compileDsl_scriptsGroovy' as it has no source files
```

The following line successfully outputs all the files I try to compile:

```
println sourceSets.dsl_scripts.allSource.matching({include '**/*.dsl'}).getFiles()
```

What do I do wrong?

**EDIT**:
I found the following snippet in gradle sources:

```
FileCollection groovyJavaOnly = spec.getSource().filter(new Spec<File>() {
    public boolean isSatisfiedBy(File element) {
       return element.getName().endsWith(".groovy") || element.getName().endsWith(".java");
    }
});

spec.setSource(new SimpleFileCollection(groovyJavaOnly.getFiles()));
```

Is it possible to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a gradle bug http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2372

Answer (score 0):

To make the gradle groovy compile tasks compile files with extension other than `.java` or `.groovy`, the new extension needs to be added to the `sourceSets` and also to the compile task's `groovyOptions.fileExtensions`.

For example, to make the `compileTestGroovy` task compile files with `.dummy` extension, in addition to `.java` and `.groovy`, the below changes would be required:

```
sourceSets.test.groovy.filter.include('**/*.dummy')

compileTestGroovy {
    groovyOptions.fileExtensions = ['java', 'groovy', 'dummy']
}
```